# Writing data to the file in android

Tags: android

This code overwrites the file....

I want my previous data to remain the same..

```
osw..append (data);
```

but did not get the result

```
public void WriteSettings(Context context, String data){ 
             FileOutputStream fOut = null; 
             OutputStreamWriter osw = null;

             try{
              fOut = context.openFileOutput("abc.txt",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);       
              osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 
              osw.write(data); 
              osw.flush(); 
              Toast.makeText(context, "Settings saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              } 
              catch (Exception e) {       
              e.printStackTrace(); 
              Toast.makeText(context, "Settings not saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              } 
              finally { 
                 try { 
                        osw.close(); 
                        fOut.close(); 
                        } catch (IOException e) { 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                        } 
              } 
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public void WriteSettings(Context context, String data){ 
         FileOutputStream fOut = null; 
         OutputStreamWriter osw = null;

         try{
          fOut = context.openFileOutput("abc.txt",Context.MODE_APPEND);       
          osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 
          osw.write(data); 
          osw.flush(); 
          Toast.makeText(context, "Settings saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } 
          catch (Exception e) {       
          e.printStackTrace(); 
          Toast.makeText(context, "Settings not saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } 
          finally { 
             try { 
                    osw.close(); 
                    fOut.close(); 
                    } catch (IOException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                    } 
          } 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [MODE_APPEND](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_APPEND) with openFileOutput.